# Print all Fields with AWK separated by OFS

Tags: awk, gawk

Is there a way to print all records separated by the OFS without typing out each column number.

```
#Desired style of syntax, undesired result
[kbrandt@glade: ~] echo "1 2 3 4" | gawk 'BEGIN { OFS=" :-( "}; {print $0}'        
1 2 3 4

#Desired result, undesired syntax
[kbrandt@glade: ~] echo "1 2 3 4" | gawk 'BEGIN { OFS=" :-) "}; {print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
1 :-) 2 :-) 3 :-) 4
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is a variation on the first style:

```
echo "1 2 3 4" | gawk 'BEGIN { OFS=" :-( "}; {$1=$1; print $0}'
```

Results:

```
1 :-( 2 :-( 3 :-( 4
```

Explanation:

the `$1=$1` is to rebuild the record, using the current OFS (you can also see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Changing-Fields)

Update:

(suggested by @EdMorton and @steve) This is a briefer, equivalent version of the awk command, that sets OFS in the command line, and takes advantage of `print $0` as the default action:

```
awk -v OFS=" :-( " '{$1=$1}1'
```

Comment: @steve note: there was one edit that replaced the block `{$1=$1; print $0}` with just `$1=$1`. That would fail for $1 == 0.

Comment: @EdMorton that's a perfectly valid alternative (`awk -v OFS=" :-( " '{$1=$1}1'`. I still like the first version 'cause it's so similar to the OP's (and I don't see any clear advantage of one over the other, mostly a question of style maybe)

Comment: @GermanGarcia: Wasn't that the _exact_ edit that I made? Personally I think `awk -v OFS=" :-( " '{$1=$1}1` is clearer, but the only reason I decided to edit was because users won't actually need `GNU awk` specifically. The command should work of other `awks` too. If we were trying to make things shorter, we could still go further: `awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=" :-( "`. HTH.

Comment: @GermanGarcia I slightly prefer the briefer version in this case as it re-inforces the concepts of using -v to assign initial values to variables and of "print $0" being the default action which are both things that if you're experienced you'll have no problem understanding and would probably naturally use and if you're inexperienced you really need to get familiar with ASAP so IMHO it had benefits for both experienced and inexperienced awk users. No big deal either way though.

Comment: You could do away with the block and go one char shorter with the slightly more obscure: `$1=$1;1`.

Comment: @steve No, it was not your exact edit. You can see your edit here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13705660/2 (it uses only the condition `$1=$1`, leaving the action part empty; but that introduces the problem of being a false condition for $1 == 0). Regarding the briefer version, I'll add that in a moment. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @EdMorton I've updated the answer to include the briefer version suggested by you and steve, so as to take those concepts into account.

Comment: @Thor `$1=$1;1` will print every line that has a non-zero/null $1 value twice which probably isn't desired. You could do `$1=$1,1` but as we discovered recently no-one knows what that means without some investigation so it should be avoided :-).

Comment: @GermanGarcia: It seems you were right! I must have forgotten to have added that `1` on the end. I blame lack of sleep ... but there's no excuse is there?

Comment: @EdMorton: doh, ignore my suggestion. Btw, `$1=$1,1` doesn't work here with gawk, it evaluates to false. Anyway the briefest clear version has already been posted.

Comment: @steve I always reserve myself one more excuse, just in case :) Regards

Comment: For some reason, this solution prints two OFS after the first record. (I can move the doubled-up OFS if I replace `$1=$1` with say `$10=$10`). Any explanation? I *can* get rid of it if I do "{$NF=$NF}1"

Comment: @davemyron I could not reproduce the behavior you mention (tried original awk, mawk and gawk). What version of awk are you using? Can you give a little example?

Comment: @GermanGarcia I ran into the issue when using an FPAT for comma-separated values: `awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1}1' <(echo "comma,separated,values")` results in `comma||separated|values`

Comment: @davemyron I've tried your sample and it does indeed print those two OFS after the first field (precisely after the $N field, except when N==NF as you already mentioned) when using FPAT. I don't know why gawk acts this way (IMHO this seems to be a bug, and using $NF=$NF as you suggest may act as a workaround) Also, it seems to work fine if you use [^,]+ instead of [^,]* ..but now you can't have empty fields inside commas

Comment: Since the question is about `OFS = "something"` being effective in the output and assumes nothing about other system variables being changed as well, I'd like to add that if one sets `FS = "\n"` as well in the `BEGIN` rule, `$1 = $1` is obviously not enough, since it is also needed to set `RS = ""` in the `BEGIN` rule. (Indeed, I've hit this question while trying to use `awk` to join all lines of a file, since simply setting `FS = "\n"` and `OFS = " "` didn't seem to work.)

Answer (score 2):

Sed equivalent:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4" | sed 's/ /:-)/g'
```

Here's another option with awk:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4" | awk '{ gsub(/\s/, ":-)")}1'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question asks about awk specifically. So an answer using sed is out of place here.

Comment: I think you sed should read `sed 's/ / :-) /g'` if you notice, the OP had a space around the smiley in the OFS