# awk: changing OFS without looping though variables

Tags: awk

I'm working on an awk one-liner to substitute commas to tabs in a file ( and swap `\\N` for missing values in preparation for MySQL `select into`).

The following link http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/211941-awk-output-field-separator.html (at the bottom) suggest the following approach to avoid looping through the variables:

```
 echo a b c d | awk '{gsub(OFS,";")}1'

 head -n1 flatfile.tab | awk -F $'\t' '{for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){gsub(" +","\\N",$j)}gsub(OFS,",")}1'
```

Clearly, the trailing `1` (can be a number, char) triggers the printing of the entire record. Could you please explain why this is working?

SO also has [Print all Fields with AWK separated by OFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704947/print-all-fields-with-awk-separated-by-ofs) , but in that post it seems unclear why this is working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk evaluates `1` or any number other than `0` as a true-statement. Since, **true statements** without the **action statements** part are equal to `{ print $0 }`. It prints the line.

#### For example:

```
$ echo "hello" | awk '1'
hello
$ echo "hello" | awk '0'
$
```