# Linux Awk - how to control output delimeter

Tags: linux, awk, delimiter

I am running the following awk command to project the 1st and 15th columns from an input file to an output . The problem start when the output file is written with a space delimeter

```
     awk -F "|" '{print $1,$15}' 1st_rm_text_from_transactions_22_7_14.plt > manual_memos_text_from_transactions_22_7_14.plt
```

How do I control the deilmeter (I need | ) in the output file ?

thanks

Comment: an example would be better. Did you want `|` as Output Field seperator? What's your input field seperator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `FS` instead of comma in the print statement.

```
awk -F"|" '{print $1FS$15}' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 3):

You control it with the output separator variable OFS

```
awk -F "|" '{OFS="|"; print $1,$15}' 1st_rm_text_from_transactions_22_7_14.plt > manual_memos_text_from_transactions_22_7_14.plt
```

A better way would be to add a begin section in order to avoid setting the variable every line (as suggested in the other answers and comments):

```
awk -F "|" 'BEGIN {OFS="|"} {print $1,$15}' 1st_rm_text_from_transactions_22_7_14.plt > manual_memos_text_from_transactions_22_7_14.plt
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704947/print-all-fields-with-awk-separated-by-ofs)

Comment: Good. In this case you can also use `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}`.

Comment: Now that I see, you are setting `OFS` every single line. This is not very optimal... It should be within the `BEGIN{}` block, as I said before, or as a parameter (the way Kent suggests).

Comment: Yes, I know, I wanted a simple solution without too many additions. I'll modify my answer to add the begin section.

Comment: For the record: On a file with 40k lines, there was virtually no difference between the two.

Comment: Interesting! I would have said that it would significantly slow down the performance. Good one.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F "|" -v OFS="|" '...code..'
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{code...}'
```