# Please explain this awk script for taking Fixed Width to CSV

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, command-line

I'm learning some awk. I found an example online of taking a fixed width file and converting it to a csv file. There is just one part I do not understand, even after going through many man pages and online tutorials:

```
1: awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='1 10 4 2 2' -v OFS=',' '
2:    { $1=$1 ""; print }
3: ' data.txt`
```

That is verbatim from the sample online ([found here](http://www.unixcl.com/2009/11/convert-fixed-length-file-to-csv-awk.html)).

What I don't understand is **line 2**. I get there is no condition, so the 'program' (contained in brackets) will always execute per record (line). I don't understand why it is doing the `$1=$1` as well as the empty string statement `"";`. However, removing these causes incorrect behavior.

Comment: That line can be better written as `{ $1=$1 } 1` and that just forces a change in record structure so that `awk` rewrites each line using `OFS` as comma

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. When I run `{ $1=$1; print }` it works! Your comment about changing the record structure to cause a rewrite was key! If you want to write an answer, I'll vote it.

Comment: Also, with that information, I was able to find a relevant SO question with some additional helpful information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704947/print-all-fields-with-awk-separated-by-ofs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1=$1` assigns a value to $1 (just happens to be the same value it already had). Assigning any value to a field cause awk to recompile the current record using the OFS value between fields (effectively replacing all FSs or FIELDSEPS spacings with OFSs).

```
$ echo 'a,b,c' | awk -F, -v OFS="-" '{print; $1=$1; print}'
a,b,c
a-b-c
```

The `""` is because whoever wrote the script doesn't fully understand awk and thinks that's necessary to ensure numbers retain their precision by converting them to a string before the assignment.

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton! Also a great reminder about following advice from internet blog posts... :)